# Will multiply insert requests to the same table with direct query and store-procedure cause collision?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Multiply users can call **store procedure(SP)**, that will make some changes to **mytable** in SQL Server. This SP should insert some rows to **mytable** that has reference to itself through **parentid** column.

```
TABLE mytable(
   id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   name varchar(20) not null,
   parentId int not null foreign key references mytable(id)
)
```

in order to insert row to such table, accordingly to other posts, I have 2 ways:

1. Allow null to **parentid** column by `ALTER TABLE mytable alter column parentid int null;`, insert the row, update **parentid** and than disable null to **parentid**
2. Allow **IDENTITY** by `set identity_insert maytable on`, insert dummy row with **id=-1** and **parentid=-1**, insert the correct row with reference  to **-1**, update the **parentid** to **SCOPE_IDENTITY()** and in the end set IDENTITY to off

**The case:**

Assume I take the **2nd** way. **SP** managed to `set identity_insert mytable on` **BUT** didn't yet finished the execution of the rest **SP**. At this time, there are other **INSERT** requests(NOT through SP) to the **mytable** table like `INSERT INTO mytable(name,parentid) VALUES('theateist', -1)`. No **id** is specified because they assumed that IDENTITY is off and therefore **id** is auto-incremental.

**The Question:**

Will this cause errors while inserting because **IDENTITY**, in this period of time, is ON and not auto-incremental any more and therefore it will require **id** specification? If yes, it will be better to use the **1st** way, isn't it?

Thank you

Comment: It's good to get into the habit of using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` rather than `@@IDENTITY` as the latter may return an ID relating to another table if mytable has a trigger on it that e.g. audits into another table.

Comment: @Will, I update my post, but this was not the issue. The issue will it cause collisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`identity_insert` is a per-connection setting - you won't affect other connections/statements running against this table.

I definitely wouldn't suggest going the first way, if it could be avoided, since it *could* impact other users of the table - e.g. some other connection could do a broken insert (`parentid=null`) while the column definition allows it, and then your stored proc will break. Also, setting a column `not null` forces a full table scan to occur, so this won't work well as the table grows.

If you did stick with method 2, you've still got an issue with what happens if two connections run this stored proc simultaneously - they'll both want to insert the `-1` row, at different times, and delete it also. You'll have conflicts.

I'm guessing the problem you're having is inserting the "roots" of the tree(s), since they have no parent, and so you're attempting to have them self referencing. I'd instead probably make the roots have a null parentid permanently. If there's some other key column(s), these could be used in a filtered index or indexed view to ensure that only one root exists for each key.

---

Imagine that we're building some form of family trees, and ignoring most of the realities of such beasts (such as most families requiring children to have two parents):

```
CREATE TABLE People (
    PersonID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    Surname varchar(30) not null,
    Forename varchar(30) not null,
    ParentID int null,
    constraint PK_People PRIMARY KEY (PersonID),
    constraint FK_People_Parents FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) references People (PersonID)
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_SoleFamilyRoot ON People (Surname) WHERE (ParentID is null)
```

This ensures that, within each family (as identified by the surname), exactly one person has a null `ParentID`. Hopefully, you can modify this example to fit your model.

On SQL Server 2005 and earlier, you have to use an indexed view instead.

Comment: @Damien, yes you right, it's the roots. So, you suggest to allow **NULL** permanently to column **parentid** and controlling inserting to the table through filters?

Comment: @theateist - yes, set the column to allow nulls, but then ensure that within each tree, only one entry has a NULL value - that's what the filtered index or indexed view will allow you to do. I'll add an example.

Comment: @Damien, is this practical? I mean, because of the multiply simultaneous connections I need to modify my table. This is what actually getting done?

Comment: @theateist - I'm not sure I understand your follow-up question. Basically though, if you're thinking about *modifying* your data definitions (e.g. `ALTER TABLE`) during normal use, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Damien, will it be ok if I'll to the following. I'll use 2nd way(`set identity_insert mytable on`), but I'll modify stored proc. Before adding dummy row I'll check if it is already exists. If id does, I'll use it without inserting new one, else I'll add it and delete at the end. Will this help?

Comment: @theateist - no, you'll still have races. If you're wanting to use this method, I'd suggest the new row you add have an ID value of `-@@SPID` - this is unique per connection, so you won't collide with other connections.

Comment: @Damien, in follow-up question I meant that I have table that holds **trees** (root->childs->childs) and I want to copy it to other table(NOT empty). The structure of the table is similar to the **People** but **parentid** doesn't allow NULLs. What is practical to do in this cases? Change the structure of the table as you suggested-allow NULLs(permantly, NOT by store proc) or add dummy row with `-@@SPID`?